# DiscordBot online but doesn't respond to command (js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I have no experience with dc bots so I followed a yt tutorial but discord.js he used was an older version (v12) so I fixed the code for my version v14. The Bot goes online but when I type a command it won't respond. There are no errors it just goes online and gives the console message that's it.
Maybe it's because of the version but I can't find any answers for this version. (Maybe it's something else as I said I've never done that before)
This is my main.js:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    ]
  })

  const prefix ='!';

  const fs = require('fs');
  client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
  for (const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  };

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});


client.on('message', message =>{
  console.log("1")
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    console.log("2")

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

The console.log() 1 and 2 are to check if it works but it won't show in the console just the "Bot is online".
Then I have a folder /commands with ping.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong!')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should request the message content intent. See how:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
      GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
  })
```

Note that you may also need to enable it in the Discord Developer Portal:
[image]

Comment: When i add that it gives me an error: throw new Error(unrecoverableErrorCodeMap[error.code]); Error [DisallowedIntents]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted.

I did enable the stuff in the Developer Portal

Comment: Yes that's what I mentioned in my message ahah, you should enable the intent at https://discord.dev

Comment: oh sorry now error is gone I did enable it I guess it took some time to work haha but the Bot still doesn't respond

Comment: add console.log(message.content)

Comment: Console stays empty it only gets "bot is online"